# How to "nc" data to socket file?

Tags: networking

I have a server listening on a socket file `/tmp/any.sock` and I want to write something to that socket. If it would be listening on a port, I would use `echo mymessage | nc localhost 1234`, but `nc /tmp/any.sock` or `echo mymessage > /tmp/any.sock`does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `nc` for it as well with the `-U` option.

#### Example

1. Open listening socket in one terminal

   ```
   nc -lU socket.sock
   ```
2. Input of data on the other terminal:

   ```
   echo mytext | nc -U socket.sock
   ```
3. Watch the `mytext` being printed on the first terminal. By default `nc` stops listening after an End-of-File character, but I assume your server can decide on its own.